# Angular 2 Ng style isn't removing old style when the model object changes

Tags: angular

I am facing this problem in my project. If you assign an object to ngStyle in a div, ngStyle doesn't flush the style properties from the older object when the object changes.

While it should be that all the old object style should be flushed, and only the new object style properties should be applied.

To show the problem,I have forked the plunkr given on [ngStyle GitHub page](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_style.ts).

You can reproduce the issue at this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/k4blRSVIHJRrloGNzSUe?p=preview).

```
<div [ng-style]="selectedStyle">
 Change style of this text!
</div>


changeFirst(){
 this.selectedStyle = {"border-width": "5px", "border-style": "solid", "border-color": "black"};
}

changeSecond(){
  this.selectedStyle = {"background-color": "red"};
}
```

In the Plunkr, click on the first style object and it will apply, it will give the div a border. Then click on the second style, it will give it the background color but also keep the border from previous style.

### Environment

Angular version: 2.0.0-alpha.39

Language: TS

Comment: check the source code of ng style..i think, it gets the difference and adds them..whereas it should flush the old properties

Comment: I'm pretty sure ngstyle is working as intended here - it adds to the existing style, but its not replacing it. It also feels like you're using it wrong? It should use styles, and then change it as needed based on an expression

Comment: @rlweb didnt understand this part - It should use styles, and then change it as needed based on an expression

Comment: You're right. I was mixing with classes. Still early in the morning here, apologies!

Comment: i thought of using classes, but my app needs to give dynamic styles..thats why i went for ng style..i remember the same app was made using angular 1, and it used to work fine..this problem is with ng 2 version of the app..thanks

Comment: What if you set selectedStyle to false or null before changing the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118389/discussion-between-lakshay-and-rlweb).

Comment: had tried it earlier..didnt work..https://plnkr.co/edit/4ok6SYNMKNuIN8J0vpkq?p=preview

Comment: turned out to be an issue in object changes code (KeyValueDiff) in angular..will be fixed in the next release (as per angular guys)

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
changeFirst(){
  this.selectedStyle = {"border":"5px solid black"}; //<----- made change here.
}

changeSecond(){
  this.selectedStyle = {"background-color": "red"};
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..this might work but the styles will be dynamic in my app..so the problem is more basic..i think the problem is with ng style only

Comment: There is no problem with ng-style. It requires proper input. I am not able to tell you exact reason why it not working with individual attribute but my suggestion works as expected with your version of Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

```
--html

<button md-button *ngFor="let mod of mappedModules;let k= index" [style.font-weight]="modStyle[k]" (click)="moduleButtonClicked(k)">{{ mod.name }}</button>

--ts
moduleButtonClicked(index: any){

    for(var i=0;i<this.modStyle.length;++i){
        if(i==index){
            this.modStyle[i]= 'bold';
        }
        else{
            this.modStyle[i]='normal';
        }
    }

}
```